# Disallow properties from derived class on assignment

Tags: typescript

Assume I have the following situation:

```
interface Base {
  a: string;
}

interface Derived extends Base {
  b: string;
}

const x: Derived = {
  a: "a",
  b: "b",
};
```

Is it possible to have the linter and/or compiler to complain about the following line:

```
const y : Base = x;
```

The purpose would be to discover that there are additional properties being assigned to `y` that do not exist in the Base class.

Comment: typescript is structural typing system, so as long as x has compatible structure with y, it can be assigned. so the answer is no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70849002/disallow-properties-from-derived-class-on-assignment#comment125249375_70849002) is correct: TypeScript is [structurally-typed](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#structural-typing).

This means that as long as you extend `Derived` from `Base`, then you cannot exclude `Base`'s properties from `Derived`.

However, you can use structural typing to create an additional type which is compatible with `Base` and excludes the "excess" properties of `Derived` by typing them as [optional properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties) of type [`never`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type) (via the help of some [type utilites](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html)), like this:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4oN4FgBQyycAXMhmFKAOYDcBAvgQaJLIigCLTABuEAE2QQAHpBACMaTDgJEARmQpUQdRs3wIA9iArIRZblX5CAvMjyFiZAERwbAGjnJFyG-MeN6+AmACeAA4oAApQEPzgAKJiEBKCoVoBGAA86FgOyEZ8gsIxElJpEAB8yOaFyABkyMFwUGDAcAA2yQBKENpQAsnRCI0ArgIQyQDWEH5aMJk8Jhmj45OFRRkg4dBFRd6+gSiFAHJaYFkmpdVhEWDR4oMCCUmpMhlHghsaAPSvyACSukEIYMhgAAWKH8QQA5FIAlBEtB6hAMCQCINerUUNpdP9XHsDk8BN55AA6ODId7kSg0AiE+Qkj59OIwUCCN4fACaWj6UFycAAtgFGihMBhgNQQNzYmBEZodHo-GRsYdpjlzCJaCSAFTOIhEAB6BAAKttkGDcWDkMApCADsQMEKRXB5PyAVoAYawfKTQTnAagkaTWaLVbBcKQPbHWBnaCUGCanUGs02h0uu5HMgVvwoOswZ6rERvfDkBNkFCYXU-Eb5KbUWaQNpeXB6g6INmtVq80blDRTebU4GbcHQyCI6609AswAKABMAGYJxOAJTINWvAhAA)

```ts
interface Base {
  a: string;
}

interface Derived extends Base {
  b: string;
}

const x: Derived = {
  a: "a",
  b: "b",
};

type PreventExtendedProps<Base, Derived extends Base> = Base & Partial<Record<Exclude<keyof Derived, keyof Base>, never>>;

type BaseNotDerived = PreventExtendedProps<Base, Derived>;

// Inspect the type's properties:
declare const b: BaseNotDerived;
b.a // string
b.b // undefined

// Your example assignment:
const y: BaseNotDerived = x; /*
      ^
Type 'Derived' is not assignable to type 'BaseNotDerived'.
  Type 'Derived' is not assignable to type 'Partial<Record<"b", never>>'.
    Types of property 'b' are incompatible.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.(2322) */
```

Comment: Interesting solution. A bit complicated but it surely seems to do the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about this...

```
type A = {
    a: string;
};

type B = {
    b: string;
};

type Derived = A | B;

const x: Derived = {
    a: "a",
    b: "b",
};

const a: A = { a: "123" };
const b: B = { b: "234" };
const d: Derived = x;

const b1: B = x; // <---- Error
const a1: A = x; // <---- Error
```

**Surely, with interface(s) alone, that won't be possible**

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I need to extend from A to get all of that too.

Comment: Take a look at algebraic types. They can help you build extended types for sure, along side the constraint that you are looking for. We can even do `A & B`.